# ARG is never substituted when building Dockerfile

Tags: python-3.x, docker, kubernetes-helm

This question has been asked around many times and I've tried so many permutations! But nothing seems to work :(

I have a Dockerfile for a simple Flask app in Python which looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
ARG env=BOOGA
MAINTAINER First Last "first.last@email.com"

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y python3-pip python3.8

# We copy just the requirements.txt first to leverage Docker cache
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

COPY . /app

ENTRYPOINT [ "python3", "src/app.py", "$env" ]
```

I try to build this container like this:

```
docker build . -t try:latest --force-rm --no-cache --build-arg env=LOCAL
```

We use `helm` for `Kubernetes`.

When the pod which houses this container is starting up, the command that's run is

```
python3 src/app.py $env
```

and not

```
python3 src/app.py LOCAL
```

which is what I specified while building my Docker image. Before incorporating `helm` I used `ENV` and a `docker run -e env=LOCAL ...` command to run my app but with `helm` I guess I don't have to do that.

How can I get the value of `$env` into the `ENTRYPOINT` command correctly substituted?

I have also tried the following to no avail:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["python3 src/app.py $env"]
ENTRYPOINT ["python3 src/app.py ${env}"]
ENTRYPOINT python3 src/app.py $env
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use an environment variable over a positional argument here:

- In your code, look at `os.environ.get('env', 'development')` to get the value.
- In your Dockerfile, don't pass it as a `ARG` or mention it in the startup-time metadata

  ```sh
  # no ARG
  CMD ["python3", "src/app.py"] # no $env
  ```
- Use the exact same Docker image in all environments.
- In your Helm `values.yaml` make it configurable

  ```yaml
  environment: default
  ```
- In your Helm template, set the environment variable

  ```yaml
  env:
  - name: env
    value: {{ .Values.environment }}
  ```
- At deploy time you can select an alternate environment

  ```sh
  docker run -e env=staging ...
  ```

  ```sh
  helm install ... --set environment=qa
  ```

---

When you use JSON-array for ENTRYPOINT or CMD (or RUN) nothing is ever substituted at all.  In the first form in your question, the script is passed the literal string `$env`; in the later forms, the container is invoked with a single word containing spaces and also the literal `$env`, and you'll get a "command not found" error when the whole thing is interpreted as a command name with no arguments.  You need to use the shell form to get variable expansion.

There's a further issue in that ARG values are [included in the environment](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#using-arg-variables), but only for RUN commands.  [Dockerfile variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement) doesn't happen for the command-type directives.  So you'd also need to explicitly set an ENV to get the value visible at container startup time.

```sh
ENV env $env                   # Relay ARG to ENV
CMD python3 src/app.py "$env"  # Not JSON-array form
```

Comment: You, sir, are AMAZING! This is an amazingly clean way to do it! I'm so glad you suggested it! :) Such a great pattern!